# fullscreen c program app not working in windows 7/8

Tags: c, bgi

Hy guys, I wrote a program to draw a line in C programming. As we know, windows7/8 doesn't support full screen directly, When I compiled from turboC++, it ran currectly, but when I build it and went to the turboC++ folder and executed from there, it gives me a message that this platform doesnt support full screen apps, now what should I do so that it runs in windows 7/8. The code I wrote is:

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void)
{
   clrscr();
   /* request auto detection */
   int gdriver = (DETECT)/3, gmode, errorcode;
   int midx, midy;

   /* initialize graphics and local variables */
   initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "C:/TURBOC3/BGI/");

   /* read result of initialization */
   errorcode = graphresult();
   if (errorcode != grOk)  /* an error occurred */
   {
      printf("Graphics error: %s\n", grapherrormsg(errorcode));
      printf("Press any key to halt:");
      getch();
      exit(1); /* terminate with an error code */
   }

   midx = getmaxx() / 2;
   midy = getmaxy() / 2;
   setcolor(getmaxcolor());

   line(midx, midy, midx/2,midy/2);

   /* clean up */
   getch();
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

what may be the solution? I am just a beginner at C... Sorry if I am not able to make you clear...
I have also attached the picture of error what I got,..[image: The error I got...]

Comment: "XY not working on Windows" - what a surprise...

Comment: Did you consider using a cross-platform GUI toolkit like Qt?

Comment: nope, since, our professor dont allow anything to use other than TurboC++, I am in TurboC++ and full screen is not working, look the question properly @H2CO3...

Comment: If possible, the _first_ thing you should do is toss TurboC in the bin. It is from fifteen-plus years ago and has no real place in modern settings, especially when you can get gcc (beer-free and speech-free) and Visual C (beer free). If you _must_ use TurboC, you're probably going to have to use it on a platform of similar vintage. Backwards compatibility isn't guaranteed to go on forever. Why educational institutions continue to use it is bizarre - they may as well be teaching you COBOL :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, yes, I am fully in support of you, I even told my professor that TurboC++ has vanished, can't we use other like code::blocks or Borland C++ then he told that, TurboC++ is in syllabus so we must use that, don't think more,... is there any solution when I am using TurboC++?

Comment: Teaching COBOL would actually be better, because there is still a demand for COBOL developers, unlike people knowing 16-bit MS-DOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dosbox for this purpose
follow the steps

> 1.Install the software DOSBox[download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dosbox/files/dosbox/0.74/DOSBox0.74-win32-installer.exe/download)
>
> 2.Download and extract TC
>
> 3.Make sure that the DOSBox and TC are in the same directory and the TC.exe application is in the Folder TC>>BIN>>TC.exe for this to work.
>
> 4.Run DOSBox and Type the following commands at the command prompt **mount d c:**
>
> 5.Now you should get a message which says: **Drive D is mounted as a local directory c:**
>   Type d: to get into **d:**
>
> 6.Next follow the commands below:
>   **cd tc**

**cd bin**

and **tc or tc.exe**

> 7.In Turbo C Editor, go to Options>Directories>Change Directories>Change the source of TC to the source directory [D]
>
> 8.Go to Program Files>DosBox folder.>DOSBox 0.74 Options> and edit it using notepad(move to the end of file)

9>.And paste the code as shown in below.

mount d c:\

d:

cd tc

cd bin

tc.exe

By the end of this step, Turbo C will load automatically as you click on DosBox icon.

Answer (score 2):

Use an emulator like DosBox - http://www.dosbox.com/

Answer (score 2):

Turbo C++ generate 16 bit binary application and it cant run in win7 32/64 bit environment. Use an emulator like DosBox

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a restart: `Control Panel > Device Manager > Display Adapters` and select `Disable`.